# Rewrite not working on ubuntu

Tags: .htaccess, ubuntu

I am using two rewrites on my Ubuntu and one of them works while the other does not.

This one works -

```
RewriteRule ^/images/(.*)$ https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/some-folder/images/$1 [L]
```

and this one does not work -

```
RewriteRule ^news/.*-(\d+)/?$ news/?view=read&newsArticleID=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

With the 2nd one I am trying to write a rewrite rule for the following URL from

https://example.com/news/lifestyle-magazines-4/chrissy-teigen-gets-her-kit-off-for-the-september-s-issue-of-women-s-health--4184/

to

https://example.com/news/?view=read&newsArticleID=4184

Any debugging tips or help please?

Comment: Where is this .htaccess located and are there more rules before this rule?